# Display discount in Layered navigation filter

Tags: layered-navigation, discount, magento-2.1.7

I have added attribute in the admin side for the `percentage of discount`. I have to display `discount with percentage` in the `layered navigation filter`. with discount range like 10% - 20%, 20% - 30% etc.

I am not getting any solution for this.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Discount Filter](https://marketplace.magento.com/rltsquare-discountfilter.html) In your magento2 project

Answer (score -1):

1) To add new attribute which you want to display in layered navigation
Go to `catalog>attribute>manage attribute`. Click on add new attribute
now you can create attribute as your required name. But some fields are required as `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner => Dropdown`
`Use In Layered Navigation => Filterable (with results)`

2) Click on Manage Label/Options tab
Add options list as your required to display in product list page and as well as in layered navigation.

3) Select any one from in option list of attribute in product edit page.

4) Referesh cache.

5) Now you can see added attributes in your layered navigation.

http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/2024

Comment: I already know which you said but i want to display discount filter in percentage range like 1% - 10%, 11% - 20%, etc.

Comment: Than you need to assign values to same attributes.